# IF condition in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a condition in a variable. I try to check if the condition is true or not.

On below example I'm assigning a condition "1=1" (which is true) to variable MyCond.
I'm trying to check if the condition in MyCond is true.
Do you please help?

---

```
Sub Test()

    MyCond = "1=1"
    If MyCond = True Then
        MsgBox "That is true"
    Else
        MsgBox "That is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Comment: no, `"1=1"` is string and it is **not** True.  `1 = 1` is an expression and it **is** true

Comment: Having a "condition in a variable" smells like bad programming practice. As Plutonix indicates, you're evaluating a string; but what you really want to do, is to evaluate two separate variables. So I am interested in how you get to the string "1=1".

Comment: exactly, how did you arrive at having a string `"1=1"` and what is the point of it?

Comment: If this really is VBA, please do not tag VB.NET.  They are two very different technologies.

Comment: If you want to evaluate two separate variables, for instance var a & var b you could simply go for If a = b Then... Not sure if anyone has understood your request yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Evaluate(MyCond)` :

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyCond As String

    MyCond = "1=1"
    If Evaluate(MyCond) Then
        MsgBox "That is true"
    Else
        MsgBox "That is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just construct a **Boolean**

```
Sub test()
    Dim myCond As Boolean
    myCond = (1 = 1)
    MsgBox myCond
End Sub
```